# Why is Jenkins build successful but not working?

Tags: java, maven, gwt, jenkins

I've a maven project (GWT - Web Application Project). Currently I'm investigation the difference between a local maven build and a build by Jenkins. My local builds (build by maven via console or eclipse maven plugin) are working local AND ON ALL other environments.

The Jenkins build is successful too but isn't working anywhere. Without changing the application context, configuration or anything else (only deployiong new war file build by Jenkins) the same application build by Jenkins failed ON ALL environments.

Note: Jenkins always checkout a fresh version of the project from a SVN repo.

If I am calling a Servlet, the Browser shows the following error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - Servlet startupServlet is not available
```

Further I get the following Exception in the catalina.out:

```
Dec 11, 2014 8:50:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve custom
SEVERE: Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=404, location=/errorpages/404.xhtml]
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet errorServlet threw exception
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1254)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:438)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:342)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
        at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:311)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Configuration not loaded. Call createConfiguration(File confDir) first.
        at com.afs.paypage.server.conf.Config.getConfiguration(Config.java:162)
        at com.afs.paypage.server.util.TemplateUtil.getDefaultConfiguration(TemplateUtil.java:59)
        at com.afs.paypage.server.util.TemplateUtil.<init>(TemplateUtil.java:49)
        at com.afs.paypage.server.util.TemplateUtil.getInstance(TemplateUtil.java:40)
        at com.afs.paypage.server.servlet.PayPageErrorServlet.init(PayPageErrorServlet.java:31)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1213)
        ... 18 more
```

The "caused by" is a custom exception and mentioned a missing config and/or missing "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve custom". "custom" is a Folder directly beside "WEB-INF" and the folder and the containing files exist! And as I said, I haven't changed any config, not event the code. Nevertheless I have double checked all the config and the code but can't find an error.

The problem is, it's working if build it locally, but the same application isn't working build by Jenkins.

For maven I've updated Java 6 to Java 8 (JDK) and updated all Jenkins Maven Plugins. But still the same behavior.

I've many other projects and all are working, build by Jenkins or build locally and the are using the same Jenkins configuration.

Any further ideas?

Comment: Is Jenkins using some other profile than what you think it should be using?

Comment: Not really, same settings as for every project. The project configuration is just a copy from a working project. I only adapted the project name, desription and SVN location.